# Responsive table using flexbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I am designing a page which has table. In responsive screen i want table to be horizontally scrollable so i used bootstraps `.table-responsive` class. Because of flex applied to its section, table responsive is not working.

My code is as follows:

```
<header class="page-header"></header>
<section class="page-content">
   <div class="container">
      //Table Style here
   <div>
</section>
<footer class="page-footer"></footer>
```

And **CSS :**

```
.page-content{
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}
```

when i remove display flex it works fine.
What should i do to overcome this?

Comment: is it what you want? https://fiddle.jshell.net/gubky6fn/ (the `border` and `min-width` are just to be easy to see the expected behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it simply by adding

```
display:block;
```

in media query to page content.